# Где лучше хранить свои функции для Django?

Tags: python, django

Есть сайт, работающий на Django 2.2.4, появилась необходимость написать функцию, которая будет парсить другой сайт и срабатывать в определенное время, так вот, в каком файле проекта/приложения Django ее лучше хранить?

Comment: В любом можете хранить. Главное вызовите её потом.

Comment: Для хранения основной части вспомогательного кода, я использую файл `scripts.py` в папке соответствующего приложения. А для запуска и выполнения с ним каких-то действий — `jobs.py`. Но это просто формальность, главное чтобы было понятно и удобно. Можно даже отдельную папку создать.

Answer (score 3):

Такую функцию лучше хранить в тасках [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) или в виде [management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-management-commands/).